# Azure AD Connect -

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365

When I set up Azure AD Connect, I initially set the single sign on method to Password Synchronization.   This syncs users passwords from the on-premises AD to the cloud (O365).  This worked fine and users can log into Office 365 (https://login.microsoftonline.com) with their domain password.

We are now moving to a 3rd party Identity Provider for SSO.  This SSO provider is not ADFS.  Per Microsoft's documentation, I am trying to set the single sign on method to **"Do Not Configure"** but it's greyed out now.  How do I disable password synchronization in favor for federated SSO with a 3rd party Identity Provider?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Steps:**

**You could try disabling the Password Synchronization via PowerShell:**

```
Set-ADSyncAADPasswordSyncConfiguration -SourceConnector $Local -TargetConnector $Remote -Enable $False
```

**Run this script:** (just replace the connector names)

```
$adConnector  = "fabrikam.com"
$aadConnector = "aaddocteam.onmicrosoft.com - AAD"

Import-Module adsync
$c = Get-ADSyncConnector -Name $adConnector
$p = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.ConfigurationParameter "Microsoft.Synchronize.ForceFullPasswordSync", String, ConnectorGlobal, $null, $null, $null
$p.Value = 1
$c.GlobalParameters.Remove($p.Name)
$c.GlobalParameters.Add($p)
$c = Add-ADSyncConnector -Connector $c     
Set-ADSyncAADPasswordSyncConfiguration -SourceConnector $adConnector -TargetConnector $aadConnector -Enable $false
```

> **What do the above steps do exactly:**

The command is  from the force password sync script as shown here (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28433.how-to-use-powershell-to-trigger-a-full-password-sync-in-azure-ad-sync.aspx) which triggers the full password sync by switching it Off and then to On. The one above is just the command for "Off" which is indicated by the switch (-Enable $false)

> **Results:**

You would notice that the Password Synchronization service would be disabled even though it may/may not be indicated through the GUI (Azure AD Connect wizard) but you can definitely trust the output of a few PowerShell commandlets which would indicate the status of the password sync given in the Verification Steps below.

> **Verification:**

**You could verify if the password synchronization is completely switched off by:**

1.Checking the value of "PasswordSynchronizationEnabled" in the output of *Get-MsolCompanyInformation* command:

```
Get-MsolCompanyInformation
```

2.Changing a User's password and then monitoring whether the "Password Sync" is triggered or not by monitoring the **Events 656
    and 657** in    the Application event log of the Synchronization
    Server.

3.You could try the "Heartbeat Script" as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-implement-password-synchronization
    to get the status of the Password Synchronization.